# pluginlib tutorial missing instructions

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial says: Open up an editor and paste the following into polygon_plugins.xml

Where should this file be located; in which folder? Or does it not matter?

This instruction is just after the title:
Making the Plugins Available to the ROS Toolchain

The tutorial seemed to be straight forward up to this point; THANKS for the tutorials!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285454/pluginlib-tutorial-missing-instructions/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Please *always* include a link to any tutorials / pages / repositories you are referring to.

**Comment by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on 2018-03-14**:
http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I edited the wiki, please have a look: http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing%20and%20Using%20a%20Simple%20Plugin#The_Plugin_XML_File

---

Originally posted by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) with karma: 229 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0